# Render word, excel files in flutter app screen

Tags: excel, flutter, file, docx

Is there any way in flutter to render word, excel files on my app screen. I have done for pdf we can do by converting word excel files to pdf if it is possible. So please anyone suggest me solution to directly render files or by converting to pdf.

I tried almost every package regarding to this some Chinese packages too but no one able to render files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft Viewer url as below:

url = `http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=` **+** `<PATH TO YOUR FILE>`

Once you have that URL you can render a webview with that URL passed in Webview. Use the package: [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

Comment: Getting this error:
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Comment: i want to render local files on app screen with images in files and after that i will highlight specific text from it.

Comment: Try setting:
javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted 
when you load the WebView, check if that helps?

Eg:
WebView(
        initialUrl: url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),

Answer (score 0):

You can try it https://pub.dev/packages/open_document for open
or https://www.convertapi.com/ convert to pdf

Comment: open_document package will open files on third party apps i want to view them on my screen like wps office

Comment: U can try https://github.com/plutext/docx4j